# How can I measure time spent in child processes?

Tags: shell, time, profiling

I have a command which invokes another command (synchronously) a couple of times. Is there a way to get the total time spent in the subcommand? In other words, is there a command similar to *time* but which can time child processes as well?

Edit 2021-02-01: I don't have the source code of the command so I can't do the timing from within the command.

Comment: I would just start the timer for each subcomand and total them.

Comment: @user1794469 Maybe I should have mentioned that I don't have the source code.

Comment: I understand children are instances of one executable known in advance (as opposed to many/random executables). Can you replace the executable with a wrapper? Maybe not system-wide; maybe by changing `PATH` or with `firejai --bind=`. Compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1345253/432690).